# How to deploy a website on Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I haven't got what to enter in fields **Username for** and **Password fo**r after the command **git push heroku master**:

```
C:\code2015>git push heroku master
Username for 'https://git.heroku.com': nemo
Password for 'https://nemo@git.heroku.com':
remote: !       WARNING:
remote: !       Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: !       Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry        
the git command.
remote: !       See documentation for details:       
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git#authentication
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.heroku.com/django-blog.git/'
```

I have read documents, but do not still understand.

```
C:\code2015>heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: nemo@yandex.ru
Password (typing will be hidden):
Authentication successful.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my situation, I have "identity crises", as I installed git through cygwin, while I used Heroku's toolbelt: heroku login successfully in DOS Command console (CMD).

For CMD, the %HOME% is c:\Users\my-id

for cygwin, $HOME is different

I found that _netrc was placed in both $HOME and %HOME%

I had to

`copy $HOME/_netrc $HOME/.netrc`
then

```
git push heroku master
```

succeeded.

Comment: I did cp $HOME/_netrc $HOME/.netrc and worked perfectly in cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be more definite.

This works for me on Windows 8.
  In cmd do:

```
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because the home folder isn't the same with the toolbelt and git when finding the `_netrc`. Can you show me the output of each of the following?

```
echo %HOME%
echo %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
echo %USERPROFILE%
echo %HOMESHARE%
```

then you'll need to find out where the `_netrc` file is, copy it into one of the paths above and find out which is the correct location. Let me know which is the correct one for you.

Comment: my all paths are ok (c:/user/me)  and there is _netrc created, but somehow GIT doesn't read it ?

Comment: git is looking in a different place for it. I'm not sure how to find out, check each of your env vars with `set`

Comment: it looks like GIT wants to use %HOME% variable. which is not set under Windows.
I set %HOME% to the same value as USERPROFILE (the place where _netrc exists)

Comment: `%HOME%` generally isn't set, if it were, everything would work. I want to know what git is using as a fallback when `%HOME%` isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem,

```
heroku login
```

was saving **_netrc** file at my user directory ( %USERPROFILE%, the same as  %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% )
but GIT didn't use that (it looks like it reads only %HOME% variable). I set

```
%HOME%
```

variable to the same value (so it is `c:\user\<my account>\`  now and there is also **_netrc** file)
and **GIT** started to work

Answer (score -1):

To have ability to push to heroku git repository you have to login with heroku gem

```
heroku login
```

and then you can use regular git commands. Just try again

```
heroku login
git push heroku master
```

Comment: yes, it's obvious, but it's just don't work, that there is a question what to do