# Authentication Failed when pushing app to heroku with Shippable

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, heroku, shippable-ci

I have set up a simple nodejs app, and I want to get it to deploy to Heroku automatically when I push to github. 
This is my shippable.yml file:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - 0.10.33

build:
  ci:
    - echo 'CI running'

  on_success:
    - git push https://git.heroku.com/cicddemo123.git master
```

and this is my .netrc file:

```
machine api.heroku.com
  login fasching.ryan@gmail.com
  password 9dr2frg5-afbg-lk01-ma90-89b69c09d53a
machine git.heroku.com
  login ryryfasch
  password 9dr2frg5-afbg-lk01-ma90-89b69c09d53a
```

The password is not a real password I just added a placeholder, but I used `heroku auth:token` to get the password that I am using.

This is the error I get in Shippable when I run a commit to github:

```
git push https://git.heroku.com/cicddemo123.git master
remote: !   WARNING:
remote: !   Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: !   Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
remote: !   See documentation for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.heroku.com/cicddemo123.git/'
```

When I run `git remote -v` this is what I get:

```
origin  https://github.com/ryryfasch/CI-CD-tutorial.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ryryfasch/CI-CD-tutorial.git (push)
```

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 OS. How do I fix this error? Do I need to add something else to the .netrc file? I am stuck, any help would be great.

I've tried these stack overflow questions to try and get help but still doesn't work:

['git push heroku master' is still asking for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810419/git-push-heroku-master-is-still-asking-for-authentication/36121567)

[How to deploy a website on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018498/how-to-deploy-a-website-on-heroku)

["Git Push Heroku Master" - Cannot login to heroku - Cloud9 IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203372/git-push-heroku-master-cannot-login-to-heroku-cloud9-ide)

[Heroku : Username for 'https://git.heroku.com': git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737329/heroku-username-for-https-git-heroku-com-git)